# Pass a custom object from C# to Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a C# class that should execute a Powershell script by passing it a Log object. Log is entirely written in C#, and should be shared across the C# code and Powershell to achieve common logging.

Can someone please tell me how I can pass the custom object from C# to Powershell and use it there?

Comment: Do you just need to pass the class or an instance?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it using runspace will solve your problem. A good explanation and examples on them you can find in the following this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C.

Just a generic idea of how to use them.

if you have script :

```
param($logger2)
$logger2.Write("logger2 Write was called");
$logger.Write("logger Write was called");
```

and you want to subsitute logger2 and logger use following code :

```
String scriptContent = // get script content
Logger logger = new Logger();
Logger2 logger2 = new Logger2();
// create ps runspace
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    // start session
    runspace.Open();
    // set variables
    runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("logger", logger);
    // supply commands
    using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        // create ps representation of the script
        Command script = new Command(scriptContent, true, false);
        // suppy parameters to the script
        script.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("logger2", logger2));
        // send script to pipeline
        pipeline.Commands.Add(script);
        // execute it
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        // close runspace
        runspace.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can share a class between PowerShell and C# by compiling your `Log` class into an assembly and use [LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in PowerShell (should work in V1 and V2)

```
$lib = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('path to your dll');
$lib.Log("Terrible things have happened!")
```

If however, you want to share an instance of a class between PowerShell and C# you could use [`SessionStateProxy.SetVariable`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HowToRunPowerShell.aspx).

Comment: Assembly.LoadFile returns an assembly, so I think there's a line missing here. Also consider `Add-Type -Path`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to use the class in a powershell script, you can put the actual `C#` code into the script itself and use that as the definition for a type.

[There is a tutorial here.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx)

Basically you use `Add-Type -TypeDefinition <C# code> -Language CSharp`

Comment: My case is little different. The Powershell script lives in file outside of the C# program, and I need to call this file with Log as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference to *system.management.automation.dll* to your project and use the [PowerShell Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell).
See the example there, it is almost ready, change the line

```
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
```

to something like:

```
ps.AddCommand(<script-path/name-of-script-in-path>).AddParameter("Log", logInstance);
```

It tells to invoke your script with the parameter `Log` which value is an instance `logInstance` to be passed in the script. The script should have the parameter `Log` and use it as `$Log` in its code:

```
param($Log)

$Log.Write("Begin ...")
...
$Log.Write("End ...")
```

Comment: I am going to try this. Can you please tell me how I can access the passed parameter from within the Powershell script itself?

Comment: @naspras - I've added this to answer.